# Youtube Background Stretch to both height and width in <body>

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

The code is simple enough, it's basically an iframe: (this code is right after the `<body>` tag.

```
<div style="position: fixed; z-index: -99; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <iframe frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/MYVIDEOID?autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp;loop=1&amp;rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;wmode=transparent&amp;hd=1"></iframe>
</div>
```

The only problem I'm getting is that my monitor is wide and when maximized, the edges on the side of the browser are black, (meaning the video only stretches so much). It will only satisfy the window size to 100% of either the height or the width.

To put in other words, if re-sized to "phone/tablet" vertical position, the video will be at 100% in width (still in 16:9 ratio), but everything above the top border and below bottom border will be black/blank space.

How would I make it so the video is always covering 100% of the background? (if width is way more than height for the 16:9 aspect ratio, it's still scaled appropriately just missing the top/bottom part of the video in "see-able" view. likewise.. if in mobile mode, the height of video is 100% of device/browser, video is still 16:9, but sides of video aren't see-able)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this resource to accomplish exactly what I needed to have done: https://vegas.jaysalvat.com/

Works best with own MP4 (or similar) uploaded resource.